# Line button animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I need to make animation lines when hover on button, 
from the middle of the top line, the line should go in different directions and change the colour.
About should work like this but, it starts on top middle:

[**codepen.io**](https://codepen.io/irenetomaini/pen/mBzOEq?q=Svg%20button%20with%20hover%20gradient&limit=all&type=type-pens)

```html
 <section class="hero">
      <div class="svg-container">
         <a class="magic-link" href="#">
            <svg class="gradient" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <defs>
                <linearGradient id="gradient">
                  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
                  <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
                </linearGradient>
              </defs>
              <rect class="rect-shape" height="60" width="320" />
              <div class="text">Hover me</div>
            </svg>
         </a>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 5):

check it out, now the line goes in clockwise direction.

just play with `.rect-shape`'s `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` properties to get the effect that you are most happy with:

```
 stroke-dasharray: 140 620;
 stroke-dashoffset: 274;
```

and for sure you can put positive or negative dashoffset values, and then you kinda change direction of animation

Take a more detailed examples here on official pages:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #EB3349;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: default;
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke-dasharray: 130 620;
  stroke-dashoffset: 274;
  stroke-width: 8px;
  fill: url(#gradient);
  /* modify this with the color you want */
  stroke: #fff;
  transition: stroke-width 1s, stroke-dashoffset 1s, stroke-dasharray 1s;
}

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #fff;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.svg-container:hover .rect-shape {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 760;
}

#gradient stop {
  transition: .5s all;
}

.svg-container:hover svg.gradient #gradient stop:first-child {
  stop-color: #EB3349;
}

.svg-container:hover svg.gradient #gradient stop:last-child {
  stop-color: #f45c43;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" height="60" width="320" />
          <div class="text">Hover me</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

To implement the idea of simultaneously animating a drawing using two lines, you can use the `stroke-dasharray` attribute. The `stroke-dasharray` attribute has several parameter pairs:

`stroke-dasharray =" dash space dash space "`

It remains to calculate the necessary values of these parameters:

Button perimeter length: `320 + 60 + 320 + 60 = 760px`

Half the length of the perimeter - this will be the length of one line - 380px

To hide the lines at the initial stage of drawing, write `stroke-dasharray = "0 380 0 380"`

In other words, a dash is 0, a space is 380, a dash is 0, a space is 380

Total: stroke length - 0, space length - 760, i.e. the line will be completely hidden

To fully show both closed lines: `stroke-dasharray = "0 0 760 0"`

We write the animation formula: `values = "0 380 0 380; 0 0 760 0"`

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #3A92CE;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke:#E4E4E4;
  stroke-width:2;
  fill:transparent;
 }

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #E4E4E4;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" id="svg1" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" id="rect1" height="60" width="320"   stroke-width="2"  />
    <polyline id="p1" points="0 0, 320 0, 320 60, 0 60, 0 0"  fill="transparent" stroke="#E4E4E4"
           stroke-width="8"   stroke-dashoffset="600" stroke-dasharray="0 380" >
     <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 380 0 380;0 0 760 0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="p1.mouseover"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  <animate id="an2"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 0 760 0;0 380 0 380"
   dur="0.5s"
   begin="an1.end"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" />  
   
   </polyline>  
   
    
          <div class="text">Bottom middle</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Top-middle**

To start the animation from another point, for example, from the middle of the top line of the button, you need to shift the starting point of the animation using the command stroke-dashoffset = "220"

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #4A4A4A;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke:#E4E4E4;
  stroke-width:2;
  fill:transparent;
 }

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #E4E4E4;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" id="svg1" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" id="rect1" height="60" width="320"   stroke-width="2"  />
    <polyline id="p1" points="0 0, 320 0, 320 60, 0 60, 0 0"  fill="transparent" stroke="#E4E4E4"
           stroke-width="8"   stroke-dashoffset="220" stroke-dasharray="0 380" >
     <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 380 0 380;0 0 760 0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="p1.mouseover"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  <animate id="an2"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 0 760 0;0 380 0 380"
   dur="0.5s"
   begin="an1.end"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" />  
   
   </polyline>  
   
    
          <div class="text">Top middle</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Top-left**

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #4A4A4A;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke:#E4E4E4;
  stroke-width:2;
  fill:transparent;
 }

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #E4E4E4;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" id="svg1" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" id="rect1" height="60" width="320"   stroke-width="2"  />
    <polyline id="p1" points="0 0, 320 0, 320 60, 0 60, 0 0"  fill="transparent" stroke="#E4E4E4"
           stroke-width="8"   stroke-dashoffset="380" stroke-dasharray="0 380" >
     <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 380 0 380;0 0 760 0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="p1.mouseover"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  <animate id="an2"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 0 760 0;0 380 0 380"
   dur="0.5s"
   begin="an1.end"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" />  
   
   </polyline>  
   
    
          <div class="text">Top left</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Top-right**

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #3A92CE;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke:#E4E4E4;
  stroke-width:2;
  fill:transparent;
 }

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #E4E4E4;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" id="svg1" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" id="rect1" height="60" width="320"   stroke-width="2"  />
    <polyline id="p1" points="0 0, 320 0, 320 60, 0 60, 0 0"  fill="transparent" stroke="#E4E4E4"
           stroke-width="8"   stroke-dashoffset="60" stroke-dasharray="0 380" >
     <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 380 0 380;0 0 760 0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="p1.mouseover"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  <animate id="an2"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 0 760 0;0 380 0 380"
   dur="0.5s"
   begin="an1.end"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" />  
   
   </polyline>  
   
    
          <div class="text">Top right</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Bottom-left**

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: purple;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke:#E4E4E4;
  stroke-width:2;
  fill:transparent;
 }

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #E4E4E4;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" id="svg1" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" id="rect1" height="60" width="320"   stroke-width="2"  />
    <polyline id="p1" points="0 0, 320 0, 320 60, 0 60, 0 0"  fill="transparent" stroke="#E4E4E4"
           stroke-width="8"   stroke-dashoffset="440" stroke-dasharray="0 380" >
     <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 380 0 380;0 0 760 0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="p1.mouseover"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  <animate id="an2"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 0 760 0;0 380 0 380"
   dur="0.5s"
   begin="an1.end"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" />  
   
   </polyline>  
   
    
          <div class="text">Bottom left</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Bottom-right**

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: purple;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke:#E4E4E4;
  stroke-width:2;
  fill:transparent;
 }

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #E4E4E4;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" id="svg1" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" id="rect1" height="60" width="320"   stroke-width="2"  />
    <polyline id="p1" points="0 0, 320 0, 320 60, 0 60, 0 0"  fill="transparent" stroke="#E4E4E4"
           stroke-width="8"   stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="0 380" >
     <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 380 0 380;0 0 760 0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="p1.mouseover"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  <animate id="an2"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 0 760 0;0 380 0 380"
   dur="0.5s"
   begin="an1.end"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" />  
   
   </polyline>  
   
    
          <div class="text">Bottom right</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```